# Vim YouCompleteMe C# semantic completion in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, vim

I recently installed [YouCompleteMe for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows/)

Semantic completion is working for every language except the one that I am using, C#. The Docs for Linux/Mac say to add `--omnisharp-completer` to the `./install.sh` Command during instalation, which obviously isn't available given my method of installation. There isn't much documentation for windows and C# semantics doesn't seem to be covered at all.

Does anyone know how to get C# semantics working on Windows?

EDIT: I have tried installing Omnisharp manually but this did not help.

EDIT: I posted an [issue](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1160) on the issue tracker and received a response but it's not much help and I cannot reply. I have installed and built OmniSharp.

Comment: Use YCM's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally Found out how to get this working.

cd into `VimFiles\Bundle\YouCompleteMe\Python\ycm\completers\cs\OmniSharpServer` and then build it with `msbuild`.

after this head into vim and load up a C# file and run the command `:YcmCompleter StartServer` (like it says in the help file)

it takes a minute but semantics for C# should work after that